# php preg_split multiple delimiters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to split using multiple delimiters including `-:|/`. Here is my current code:

```
preg_split( "/ [-:|] /", $body);
```

Now I have problem with `/`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the delimiting character inside a regular expression, escape it using a `\`.

```
preg_split("/ [-:|\\/] /", $body);
```

Better, you can use other any other delimiter. Various characters will work:

```
preg_split("@ [-:|/] @", $body);
preg_split("# [-:|/] #", $body);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_split( '~[-:|/]~', $body);
```

ps: and, I suppose, there should be no spaces around [ ], but it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split( "~ [-:/|] ~", $body);
```